# Telnet : Connection refused

Tags: ssh, debian, vmware-player, telnet

I have Windows 8 as my OS and have Debian installed on VMware player. 
I would like access my debian install using telnet. 
(I do know telnet is insecure.  It's just for learning purposes)

When I use 
`telnet 192.168.119.132`, I get `connection refused`. 
I can log in via `ssh` but I would like to use telnet.

Debian can support `telnet`, I believe.
How do I enable its `telnet` support?
What firewall/networking things do I also have to enable/adjust?

Comment: Does debian even allow telnet by default? Maybe you need to enable / install the telnet daemon? (or add exception for telnet port 23)

Comment: Yes debian does allow telnet. 
How do I do that ? Please help

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure that the packages `inetutils-inetd` and `telnetd` are installed. If this is the case, in the file `/etc/inetd.conf` you should find a line that looks like this:

```
telnet  stream  tcp     nowait  telnetd    /usr/sbin/tcpd   /usr/sbin/in.telnetd
```

Make sure it isn't commented using a `#` character at the front of the line (after modifying the line use `/etc/init.d/inetutils-inetd restart` to use the updated configuration)

To check if the telnet daemon is running, execute `netstat -lnt`. In the output you should see a line like this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

The '23' is the telnet port, indicating that some service is listening for incoming connections on that port.